# Stand alone Selenium tool in a protected environment?

Tags: java, windows, selenium, mozilla

I am working in a highly protected environment in a corporate company. I have been assigned to work on selenium. They use virtual machine (Windows) here and Internet is not accessible. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way I can install the plug in to Mozilla Firefox without internet?
2. Is there any standalone application of Selenium which can be used as desktop application     without the use of internet?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Download the IDE. E.g.: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/2.5.0/selenium-ide-2.5.0.xpi

2 - Copy it into your VM

3 - Drag and drop the file directly into your FF

4 - Install it like usual

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, but how do i install or add the .xpi file as a firefox plugin?

Comment: Ask I said, drag and drop the file directly to your firefox, firefox will do the rest automatically. You may need to click Install -> restart

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead:

1. to download "Selenium Builder" from this url: http://www.saucelabs.com/addons/selenium-builder-latest.xpi

2 - Copy it into your VM

3 - Drag and drop the file directly into your FF

4 - Install it like usual

Also, in a protected environment you will probably also want to run a Selenium Grid.   I created some .bat scripts that can start a Grid and Node instance in the root directory of this OLD project I created:  https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate

Also, I created a framework for running Selenium Builder scripts on SauceLabs.com  but you could, in theory, modify it to run tests on your own private Selenium Grid instead:  http://djangofan.github.io/simple-selenium-builder-framework/